# How to detect finger location in function

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use double click. I have written function doubleTap. How to recognize location of finger?

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTap")
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}
func doubleTap()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the gesture recognizer as a parameter

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapFunc))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}

func doubleTapFunc(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    // Use 'sender' here to get the location
    if sender.state == .ended {
        // handling code
        let location = sender.location(ofTouch: 0, in: self.view!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `#selector` syntax. That will find the error with the invalid selector you have right now in your code :)

Comment: I can not compile code.
Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to variable 'doubleTap'

Comment: So you didn't copied it correctly or you copied not the latest version. try to copy now, ill try too

Comment: Override your own code because I changed the name of your callback

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location(ofTouch:in:)` to get the location of the touch. However, you need access to the gesture recognizer from inside the function where you want to access the location, so you should declare `doubleTap` as an instance property of your class.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.doubleTap))

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    }
    func doubleTap(){
        let touchLocation = doubleTap.location(ofTouch: numberOfTouches-1,in: nil)
    }
}
```

Change the input parameters to the function if you want to change whether you need to get the first or last touch's location or if you want to get the location relative to a subview.

Comment: You can also get the `UIGestureRecognizer` as a parameter of the `doubleTap` function. And you should use the `#selector` syntax.

Comment: @Sulthan updated my answer, I just copied OP's code, but you're right, I should've corrected the selector syntax. As for sending the recognizer as a parameter, that's another possibility as well.